# Hydra saying cracking done and displaying random passwords

Tags: linux, hydra

I have Hydra on my Linux machine. I want to test cracking security with Hydra on SMTP but I get no success. After about 20 messages that SMTP mechanism and a random message like `[465][smtp] host: smtp.***.com   login: ***   password: ***`
 Sometimes I get a few messages like this with other random wordlist items.
And please do not mark this as duplicate, this hasn't been answered anywhere. Another post about it was with another interface, though.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem.
The main thing to do when dict attacking emails is to add 'www.' before it.